# Memory device output in shell modification

Tags: shell, vmware

I am trying to filter some output in shell, from a command in VMware, and I wish to change the output in some way.

The command is basically printing all the memory devices manufacturer in order.
However, if there are memory slots that are not populated, it gives the "NO DIMM" output. I wish to change that output to "No Memory Installed".

The command I use to give me the output for the memory manufacturer is:

```
smbiosDump | egrep 'Memory Device: | Location: | Manufacturer:' | egrep -i 'samsung|hynix|micron|no' | awk '{print $2" "$3}'
```

and the output is this:

```
"Hynix"
"NO DIMM"
"Hynix"
"NO DIMM"
"Samsung"
"NO DIMM"
"Samsung"
"NO DIMM"
"NO DIMM"
"NO DIMM"
"NO DIMM"
"NO DIMM"
"Hynix"
"NO DIMM"
"Hynix"
"NO DIMM"
"Samsung"
```

As you can see, if there are no memory devices installed, it gives the output "NO DIMM". I wish to somehow change that to "No Memory Installed", but I do not know how to do.

Could anyone please help me out?

Comment: What have you tried? For example `| perl -ple 's/NO DIMM/No Memory Installed/'` would work, but then, I would move the whole pipeline into `perl`: perl -wle 'open my $bios, "smbiosDump |" or die "Couldn't start smbiosDump: $!"; print for map { s/NO DIMM/No Memory Installed/ } grep { /samsung|hynix|micron|no/i } grep { /Memory Device: | Location: | Manufacturer:/ } <$bios>;'` - but if you can show us representative input data, maybe a better approach becomes available,.

Comment: actually, i just remembered a command in awk, it's gsub, and it should look something like this:  | awk '{gsub ("string_to_replace", "String_to_replace_with", $column); print $column}'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 | awk '{gsub ("string_to_replace", "String_to_replace_with", $column); print $column}'
```

Comment: Might as well show them how to use awk to eliminate the `grep` usage too; there's no reason to use both tools.